# Как разделить двумерный список, на две неравные части?

Tags: python, список

Есть двумерный список `a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`. Как мне его разделить на две части, чтобы в конце стало так:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

напрямую и разделяйте

```
a, b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что так можно)

Answer (score 0):

С обобщением (не только на python)

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
a = data[0] # [1,2,3]
b = data[1] # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```